# Sonata Admin - Display attribute for each entity from sonata_type_collection in configureFormFields

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

all is in the title,

Actually I have this in my sonata admin :

```
/**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('images', 'sonata_type_collection', [
                'label' => 'admin.solution_page.images',
                'required' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ], [
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'sortable' => 'position',
                'link_parameters' => array('context' => 'image'),
                'admin_code' => 'app.admin.solution_page_has_image'
            ]);
}
```

Also I would like to display for each of my entity the media tag if a media is selected.

The current display :

[image]

Thanks in advance for your time.